# SQUID3 SSL (I built with --enable-ssl)

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, squid

Right, so the issue i have is this. (I installed my certificate) whenever i try to access a HTTPS page when i have the SECURE proxy settings plumbed into advanced settings on windows.
I am greeted with a lovely message saying ERR_CONNECTION_RESET (on all HTTPS sites, im still fine for non HTTPS). I figured I would try to be helpful by posting my config & log.

Config here: http://pastebin.com/sGpNk4d0
Log here: http://pastebin.com/jDYbqtTh

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please see [help] for questions appropriate to Stack Overflow

Comment: Unsure of how this is of help Kevin, are you suggesting this SHOULD NOT be posted here?